# How to properly escape question mark in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex below that should detect interrogative sentence. But the problem is it does not include the question mark when I test it in regexr.com

Someone knows what is missing? thanks

---

Here's my regex (i tried to use double backlash but still not work):

```
\bWhat’s up\\?\b
```

Tested string: *"Subject: What’s up? Christie"*

Here's regexr: https://regexr.com/65l08

Image:
[image]

Comment: In a `RegExp` literal, you only need a single backslash, ie `\?`

Comment: A single backslash is the correct way to escape a question mark `\?`. The reason your regex is not working is the `\b` at the end. You have a question mark followed by a space, so there is no word boundary there and the regex will not find one. I think your regex needs some rethinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

Firstly to escape a `?` character, you only need a single backslash. Two backslashes will match a literal `\` character. ([MDN: Character Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes))

Secondly, a `?` is not a word character. `\b` matches the boundary between a word and a non-word character: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions

Comment: i'm sorry new to regex. i tried to remove the boundary at the end and it is now working.